# How to fix Unprotected SMS BroadcastReceiver lint warning

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter, android-permissions, android-lint

My app needs to be able to receive SMS messages. It all works, but I get this lint warning:

> BroadcastReceivers that declare an intent-filter for SMS_DELIVER or
>   SMS_RECEIVED must ensure that the caller has the BROADCAST_SMS
>   permission, otherwise it is possible for malicious actors to spoof
>   intents.

How do I "ensure that the caller has the BROADCAST_SMS permission"?

In my manifest I have:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
<application ...>
    <receiver
        android:name=".SmsReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:priority="1000">
            <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
</application>
```

My code:

```
public class SmsReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public SmsReceiver() {}

    @Override
    public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {

        final Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
        if (bundle != null) {
            final Object[] pdusObj = (Object[]) bundle.get("pdus");
            for (int i = 0; i < pdusObj.length; i++) {
                final SmsMessage currentMessage = SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdusObj[i]);
                // use currentMessage
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Add `android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS"` to the opening `<receiver>` tag. For example:

```xml
<receiver
    android:name=".SmsReceiver"
    android:exported="true"
    android:permission="android.permission.BROADCAST_SMS">
```

This `android:permission` attribute on a `<receiver>` specifies which permission the *sender* of the broadcast must hold in order for it to be able to broadcast to your `<receiver>`. It's a security measure; in this case, so you can be relatively certain that it is the system sending the `SMS_RECEIVED` broadcast. It's not strictly required, but lint will complain if it's not there, obviously.